# Як перекласти "bleeding edge"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

> **Bleeding edge** технології - це настільки нові технології, що вони можуть нести високий ризик для тих хто почав їх використовувати.
>   Термін bleeding edge сформувався як алюзія до подібних термінів
>   *leading edge* і *cutting edge*. Зазвичай він має на увазі ще більше просування вперед, хоч і зі збільшеним ризиком через ненадійність
>   програмного чи апаратного забезпечення. Перший задокументований
>   приклад використання цього терміну мав місце 1983 року, коли невідомий
>   нині службовець банку використав це щодо Storage Technology
>   Corporation.
>
> За своєю природою, частина таких технологій увійде до панівної
>   тенденції. Наприклад, електронна пошта колись вважалась *bleeding
>   edge* технологією.

Тобто *leading edge* це *передній край* технологій. *Cutting edge* можна перекласти як *гострий край*, край об який можна порізатись. То *bleeding edge* - це край об який ти вже порізався. Як би це перекласти?

Comment: Технології в стадії випробування

Comment: @Miroshko це щось схоже на означення цього терміну

Comment: Cutting edge це скоріш "проривні технології" те що ріже тканину невідомого ;) А "Bleeding edge" можуть бути "експериментальні новітні" технології

Answer (score 5):

Дослівний переклад edge у цих прикладах як «край» — груба помилка.

Cutting edge, leading edge та bleeding edge у вказаному автором теми контексті — це нерозривне поняття, не пов’язане напряму з краєм, а використовується в метафоричному сенсі. Ось що каже про них словник Колінза (кембридзький та оксфордський практично не відрізняються в цих тлумаченнях):

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cutting-edge
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leading-edge
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bleeding-edge

Усі вони одним із визначень подають ось це:

> If you are at the cutting / leading / bleeding edge of a particular field of activity, **you are involved in its most advanced or most exciting developments.**

Про край тут і близько не йдеться. Окрім того, це все синоніми, які не мають переваги один над одним, тобто *cutting edge tech* не буде кращою за *bleeding edge tech*.

Тому найближчими за значенням і тлумаченням відповідники в українській можуть бути наступні синонімічні варіанти:

- [передові](http://sum.in.ua/s/peredovyj) (*2. Вищий за інших рівнем свого розвитку*);
- [прогресивні](http://sum.in.ua/s/PROGhRESYVNYJ) (*Який сприяє прогресу; політично, суспільно, економічно передовий.*);
- [новітній](http://sum.in.ua/s/novitnij) (*2. Новий, що відповідає сучасним вимогам; найновішого типу, конструкції і т. ін.*);
- найновіші;
- сучасні.

Comment: але ж кажуть *передній край*, чому не може бути переднього краю у технологій?

Comment: І як ви відрізните *cutting, leading* та *bleeding?*

Comment: @Yola, а чи є сенс їх відрізняти?

Comment: @Yola щодо чого кажуть «передній край»?
І так, зазвичай їх не пишуть не те що в одному реченні, а й в одному абзаці. Це просто синоніми, і ставитися до них в українській потрібно відповідно.

Comment: @Sasha Не обов'язково, звісно, але було б добре.
[Are You on the Cutting Edge or the Bleeding Edge?](https://www.myersbarnes.com/blog/2017/06/are-you-on-the-cutting-edge-or-the-bleeding-edge/), [When the leading edge becomes the bleeding edge.](https://greygoosegraphics.com/blog/2019/03/06/when-the-leading-edge-becomes-the-bleeding-edge/)

Comment: Можна спробувати в інеті пошукати. Мені Гугл на першій сторінці видав *передній край оборони* і *передній край порома*.

Comment: @Yola Я саме до того й веду, що вживання «передній край» не стосується передового чи чогось новітнього. Передній край порома — це фізичний бік порома, а передній край оборони — «…лінія на місцевості, що з'єднує найближчі до ворога оборонні окопи…», тобто також не стосується тих значень, які закладені в цій темі.

Comment: В описі, який ви навели сказано, що це найпросунутіші технології. Отже, якщо ми на відрізку прямої впорядкуємо технології за рівнем просунутості, то найпросунутіші опиняться з одного краю.

Comment: Щодо краю (і цей відтінок також є у слові "передовий") - тут метафора подібна до [фронтиру](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80), яка використовується як до наукових (квантова фізика, генна інженерія) так і до технічних (космічна тематика) досягненнь. Області дослідженнь поділяються на: 1) те що добре вивчене і залишилося багато роботи для "бухгалтерів" (треба багато людей-операторів пристроїв для розшифровки ДНК різних організмів - скоріше індустріальні а не суто наукові методи); 2) те що невивчене і потребує створення нових підходів, методів, ідей...

Comment: ...Оце друге і є фронтир, де не можна робити довготривалі плани де ситуація постійно змінюється: те що здавалося проривом стає глухим кутом, а непомітна область (як теорія абсолютно чорного тіла) раптом стає джерелом великих нових напрямків. Тому тут є порівняння і з границею між територіями "ковбоєв" та "індіанців" ("фронтир") або лінією фронту між військами і супротивником ("передній край"). Передній край (або "передові війська") він тому і передній, бо є спрямованість від впорядкованої території до нової, у напрямку до якої відбувається рух і куди прямує науковий, технологічний розвиток.

Comment: Я б додав "авангард" до цього списку як варіант перекладу "bleeding edge", разом з "передовими технологіями" утворюють ту ж алюзію, що і bleeding edge -- cutting edge, але не з лезом ножа, а з військовими формаціями, хоча можливо я їх плутаю.

Answer (score 2):

У статті, посилання на яку дав Yola, [Are You on the Cutting Edge or the Bleeding Edge?](https://www.myersbarnes.com/blog/2017/06/are-you-on-the-cutting-edge-or-the-bleeding-edge/), автор пояснює різницю метафор "Cutting Edge" та "Bleeding Edge". За його словами<sup>1</sup>, обидва вирази - це назви різних [частин](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%B6#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8) ножа:

[image: Складові частини ножа]

- Cutting edge - лезо або ріжучий край (4);
- Bleeding edge - вістря або носок (3).

Відповідно автор проводить різницю між "Cutting edge" технологіями, які "ріжуть" - найкращим чином відповідають сучасним потребам та "Bleeding edge" технологіями, які проколюють, пронизують, проривають - тобто виходять за межі звичайних можливостей<sup>2</sup>.

Отже "Being on the Bleeding Edge" це "знаходитися на вістрі технологій".

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Мені не вдалося знайти підтвердження що термін "bleeding edge" дійсно існує, принаймні у [відповідній](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife) статті Вікіпедії він не згадується.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Далі автор згадує метафору [фронтиру](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83): "Are you daring enough to explore new territory, even if it’s difficult, scary, or poses a threat to your livelihood?" - "Чи ви достатньо сміливі щоб досліджувати нову територію, навіть якщо це важко, страшно або загрожує вашим засобам існування". Ця метафора часто використовується для опису розвитку наукових знань та технологій: розширення освоєних територій, рух від освоєного до нового, невідомого, небезпечного. Слово "[передовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/peredovyj)" - це також військовий термін: "Який перебуває, діє попереду, в авангарді, найближче до ворога (про війська)".</sub>

<sub>Ці метафори підкреслюють різницю між давно відомими галузями знань, де робота ведеться в основному екстенсивно - додаються нові деталі, проводиться каталогізація і т.і.  та пошуком відповідей на відкриті питання, які потребують створення нових підходів, методів і ідей.</sub>

<sub>Прикладом першого варіанту є сучасна ситуація у біології: там зараз є велика потреба у вчених-"техніках" (лаборантах) які фактично є операторами машин, що секвенують ДНК різних організмів. Роботи багато, але проривних відкриттів тут не очікується - це стабільне джерело статей у журналах, все можна спланувати, легко знайти спонсорів і результати більш-менш відповідають очікуванням.</sub>

<sub>Приклад другого варіанту - ситуація коли неможливо передбачити коли і що стане тим самим проривом, який дасть відповіді на нові питання або нові можливості. Таким була у класичній фізиці незначна (як тоді здавалося) теорія абсолютно чорного тіла, з якої раптом виросла вся фізика 20-го сторіччя.</sub>

Comment: «Мені не вдалося знайти підтвердження що термін „bleeding edge“ [стосовно ножів] дійсно існує» — справді, створюється враження, що автор тієї статті помиляється  щодо походження виразу «bleeding edge technology». [Відповідна стаття у Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding_edge_technology) каже, що це «алюзія на „leading edge“ та „cutting edge“».